# Using Multiple when and then block in the code how to handle error

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm using geb,spock using groovy, i'm using feature for multiple blocks in the feature. But one block is failed than immediately exit from the loop.
for example:-

```
 def "test"(){
    given:
        println(" checking 3 nos")

    when:
         def a = 5
         def b = 10
         def c = 20
          if (a < b)
            println("Hi, I'm Pass")
    then:
        true

    when:
         def a1 = 5
         def a2 = 10
         def a3 = 20
          if (a2 > a3)
            println("Fail")
    then:
    false

    when:
        def a11 = 5
        def a22 = 10
        def a33 = 20
          if (a33 > a11)
            println("Hello, i'm pass")
    then:
    true
```

But here it reruns only Hi, I'm Pass but not executing third block, not return second block answer. Please guide me.

Comment: Can you explain better?  What's `then: true` and `then: false` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Second then block executes false and the test is failing which is the expected behavior. What is your expected result?

Comment: Tim_yates, given, when and then is syntax. Given is the feature, when is the flow and then is return type. if second blocks fails its not continuing third block. so how to make run third block, through second is   failed.

Comment: As Jon mentioned in his answer, you can create a separate test for the third block. That probably would make more sense if third block has no dependency on first and second block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how can you continue running each when/then after a previous one fails, then the answer is that you can't. A single test method will halt on the first failure. If you want individual tests, make multiple methods.

```
def 'test1'() {
    when:
    ...

    then:
    ...
}

def 'test2'() {
    when:
    ...

    then:
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. Split your code into multiple tests with when/then block in each of them.

You can also move some setup code to `setupSpec()` and `setup()`